# Ubuntu ping/search not working

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, dns, ping, ubuntu-server

I'm new to Ubuntu Server 14.04, and I'm trying to ping Google to see if I can reach the outside world. I have searched, but I can't figure out the problem. I'm connecting via my wireless router, not a wired connection. I set up my `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 1**.168.1.**
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 1**.168.1.*
dns-nameservers 1**.168.1.*
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

When I try to ping 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 or google.com it gives me these errors, 8.8.8.8 (`destination host unreachable`) or google.com (`ping:unknown host www.google.com`)

I’m having a tough time, but I searched the internet and tried a bunch of stuff to no avail, so I set it all back to the above.